# How to update data in rails with two parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I want to update data but I don't use find by id; instead, I search for id and date to get data.
Here is my code:

```
def update_time
 # get the parameters
 puts 'update time'
 date = params[:date]
 status=params[:status]
 empid=params[:empid]

 # find the timerecords
 @timerecords = Timerecords.where(empid: empid, date: date.to_date)

 puts 'after find'
 # update the timerecords
 @timerecords.update_attributes(timeout: Time.zone.now, status: status, empid: empid)
 puts 'after update'
 redirect_to @timerecords
end
```

The program won't execute the update. Upon search, it immediately returns this error.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for # <Timerecords::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x82b6000>):
app/controllers/timerecords_controller.rb:24:in `update_time'
```

This is the code in line 24

```
@timerecords.update_attributes(timeout: Time.zone.now, status: status, empid: empid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `first` to the query,

```
@timerecords = Timerecords.where(empid: empid, date: date.to_date).first
```